# How to share environment variables between jobs with different images in gitlab?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I have the following gitlab pipeline (builds a Java application):

```yaml
image: myregistry.com:5000/maven-ci-slave:latest

before_script:
  - export PROJECT_VERSION=$(grep -m1 '<version>' pom.xml | grep -oP  '(?<=>).*(?=<)')

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

stages:
  - build
  - .post

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn -B clean install

external-service:
  stage: .post
  image: registry.gitlab.com/finestructure/pipeline-trigger:2.6.0
  script:
    - trigger -h mydomain.com -a "auth token" -e ENV_VARIABLE=$PROJECT_VERSION -p "pipeline-token" -t branch-name project-path
```

In this pipeline, I need to extract project version from `pom.xml` (I'm this doing with a linux bash command), and store it in a environment variable (`PROJECT_VERSION`). Additionaly, this pipeline is intended to trigger a dependent pipeline (`external-service`) passing the environment variable as parameter. However, as the `external-service` job runs over a different docker image, my environment variable value is not acessible in the script directive, and the parameter is sent empty to the external pipeline.

The question is, how can I pass an env variable for a job running with a different image?

Answer (score 2):

The way I found to solve this problem was passing the environment variables using the `artifacts` mechanism. Following, I present the solution:

```yaml
image: registry.com:5000/maven-ci-slave:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - target/
    - .m2/repository/

stages:
  - build
  - .post

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn -B clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.com:4000
    - export MAVEN_VERSION=$(grep -m1 '<version>' pom.xml | grep -oP  '(?<=>).*(?=<)')
    - echo "export MAVEN_VERSION=$MAVEN_VERSION" >> sharedvars.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - sharedvars.sh

external-service:
  stage: .post
  image: registry.gitlab.com/finestructure/pipeline-trigger:2.6.0
  before_script:
    - . ./sharedvars.sh
  script:
    - trigger -h mygitlab.com -a "auth token" -e "MAVEN_VERSION=$MAVEN_VERSION" -p "service token" -t branch project
```